# Android: Displaying days since received message after 24 hours pass

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the following code in my Android app that splits the the date/time value retrieved from SQL and displays the number of minutes/hours since the message was received:

```
//Splits the date and time string retrieved from SQL into two separate strings, 
//and stores them into an array
String[] dt_array = m1.getTime().split(" ");
//String date = dt_array[0]; 
String time = dt_array[1]; 


//Splits the time into two strings, one for hours and one for minutes, and stores them
//into an array
String[] timeSplit = time.split(":");
String hourString = timeSplit[0]; 
String minuteString = timeSplit[1];

//converts the new separate time strings to integer variables
int msgHour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);
int msgMinute =Integer.parseInt(minuteString);

Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();

//retrieves current hour and minute from device and stores in separate ints 
int currentHour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int currentMinute = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

int hoursSince; 
int minutesSince;
String timeDisplay = null;


if (currentHour != 1)
{
    //tells app to display minutes if message was received under an hour ago
    if(currentHour - msgHour < 1)
    {

        minutesSince = currentMinute - msgMinute;
        //if only a minute has passed, text should read "1 minute ago", otherwise use plural "minutes"
        if (minutesSince == 1)
            timeDisplay = minutesSince + " minute ago";
        else
            timeDisplay = minutesSince + " minutes ago";
    }
    else if (currentHour - msgHour >= 1)
    {
        hoursSince = currentHour - msgHour;
        timeDisplay = hoursSince + " hours ago";
    }

} 
else
{
    //for messages that were received at a 12th hour, if the hour is currently 1, correctly displays 1 hour ago
    if(msgHour == 12 && currentHour == 1)
    {
        hoursSince = 1;
        timeDisplay = hoursSince + " hours ago";
    }

}
```

What I want is to add a function that displays days since received if the hour count goes above 24. I know this should be easy, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of determining the amount of time since the message was posted is over complicated and prone to issues when minutes and hours roll over. Something like this would be much more simple:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); //change format as needed
Date messageDate = formatter.parse(date);
long since = System.currentTimeMillis() - messageDate.getTime();
long seconds = since/1000;
long minutes = seconds/60;
long hours = minutes/60;
long days = hours/24;
```

And from there, building the message you want should be trivial for you.

Comment: Doesn't parse require (String, ParsePosition)? What would the argument for parse() be then?

Comment: There is also a `parse(string)` method (inherited from the `DateFormat` object). To use the method with `ParsePosition` you'd do `formatter.parse(date, new ParsePosition(i))` where `i` is the index in the string where the date starts.

Comment: Ok, I had to split the declaration and instantiation of messageDate so I could surround it in a try-catch block. That's the only way it wanted to compile. Hopefully that doesn't cause any headaches for me. Thank you!